# Gradient of Coefficient of Variance

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-calculus, gradient-descent

I have a d×n matrix called M. What is the best 1×d W that minimizes CoV(WM) which is Coefficient of Variance of W×M, considering that W sums to 1

$$\underset{W}{\operatorname{argmin}}\frac{SD(WM)}{Mean(WM)}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{d} w_{i}=1$$

I can rewrite this as:
$$\underset{W}{\operatorname{argmin}} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\left\|W M-\frac{1}{n} W M 
 A\right\|_{2}^{2}}}{\frac{1}{n} W M A}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{d} w_{i}=1$$

A is a n×1 matrix of ones.
I hope I get a closed form for W* or have the gradient so i can use gradient descent to find the minimum.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\r#1{\color{red}{#1}}\def\g#1{\color{green}{#1}}$
The following derivation is complicated, but results in a closed-form solution, i.e.
$$W^T = (MCM^T)^+MA + \Big(I-(MCM^T)^+MCM^T\Big)q$$
where $C$ is the Centering Matrix $(I-\frac{1}{n}AA^T),\;H^+$ denotes the pseudo-inverse of a matrix, and $q$ is an arbitrary vector (which is zero for the least-norm solution).

---

Introduce an *unconstrained* vector $x$ and use it to construct a column vector $w$ which satisfies the constraint. 
$$\eqalign{
&w = \frac{x}{{\tt1}^Tx} \quad\implies\quad {\tt1}^Tw = \frac{{\tt1}^Tx}{{\tt1}^Tx} \doteq {\tt1} \\
}$$
Then for algebraic convenience, define some auxiliary variables
$$\eqalign{
{\tt1} &= A,\quad &J = AA^T \\
C &= I-\tfrac{1}{n}J\quad &({\rm Centering\, Matrix}) \\
w &= W^T \quad &({\rm column\, vector\, constructed\, from\, }x)\\
y &= M^Tw  \quad&\implies dy = M^Tdw \\
z &= Cy  \quad&\implies dz = CM^Tdw \\
\alpha &= {\tt1}^Tx \quad&\implies d\alpha = {\tt1}^Tdx \\
\beta &= {\tt1}^Ty \quad&\implies d\beta = {\tt1}^Tdy = {\tt1}^TM^Tdw \\
w &= \alpha^{-1}x \quad&\implies dw = \alpha^{-1}dx - x\alpha^{-2}d\alpha \\
 & \quad&\implies dw = \alpha^{-1}(I - w{\tt1}^T)\,dx \\
}$$
Note that $C^T=C=C^2\;$ and 
$\;\beta={\tt1}^TM^Tw=\r{w^TM{\tt1}}=WMA$ 

these properties will be used in several of the steps below.

Use the new variables to simplify the vector appearing in the numerator.
$$\eqalign{
&\Big(WM-\tfrac{1}{n}WMAA^T\Big)^T = \Big(M^Tw - \tfrac{1}{n}JM^Tw\Big)
 = Cy = z \\
}$$
Call the objective function $\phi$, and start by differentiating its square.
$$\eqalign{
\phi^2 &= n\beta^{-2}z^Tz \\
2\phi\,d\phi &= 2n\beta^{-2}z^Tdz - 2n\beta^{-3}z^Tz\,d\beta \\
d\phi
 &= n\phi^{-1}\beta^{-3}z^T\Big(\beta\,dz - z\,d\beta\Big) \\
 &= n\phi^{-1}\beta^{-3}z^T\Big(\beta\,CM^T - z{\tt1}^TM^T\Big)\,dw \\
 &= n\phi^{-1}\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-3}z^T\Big(\beta\,CM^T - z{\tt1}^TM^T\Big)\,\Big(I - w{\tt1}^T\Big)\,dx \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}
 &= n\phi^{-1}\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-3}\Big(I - {\tt1}w^T\Big)\,\Big(\beta\,MC - M{\tt1}z^T\Big)z \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero.
$$\eqalign{
\Big({\tt1}w^T\Big)\,\Big(\beta\,MC - M{\tt1}z^T\Big)\,z
  &= I\Big(\beta\,MC - M{\tt1}z^T\Big)\,z \\
}$$
Eliminate $z$ in favor of $w$.
$$\eqalign{
\Big({\tt1}w^T\Big)\,\Big(\beta MC - M{\tt1}w^TMC\Big)\,CM^Tw
  &= \Big(\beta MC - M{\tt1}w^TMC\Big)\,CM^Tw \\
\Big({\tt1}w^T\Big)\,\Big(\beta I - M{\tt1}w^T\Big)\,MCM^Tw
  &= \Big(\beta I - M{\tt1}w^T\Big)\,MCM^Tw \\
\Big(\r{\beta}{\tt1}w^T - {\tt1}\r{w^TM{\tt1}}w^T\Big)\,MCM^Tw
  &= \Big(\beta I - M{\tt1}w^T\Big)\,MCM^Tw \\
0 &= \Big(\beta I - M{\tt1}w^T\Big)\,MCM^Tw \\
M{\tt1}w^T\g{MCM^Tw} &= \beta\,\g{MCM^Tw} \\
\Big((M{\tt1})w^T\Big)\g{v} &= \beta\g{v} \\
Bv &= \beta v \\
}$$
The last line is an eigenvalue equation.
Since the matrix $B$ is rank-${\tt1}$, there is only one non-trivial eigenvector, which miraculously allows for a closed-form solution to the problem.
$$\eqalign{
v &= M{\tt1} \qquad\qquad\big({\rm eigenvector\,of\,}B\big) \\
(MCM^T)w &= M{\tt1} \\
w &= (MCM^T)^+M{\tt1} + \Big(I-(MCM^T)^+MCM^T\Big)q \\
}$$
where $H^+$ denotes the pseudo-inverse of $H$ and $q$ is an arbitrary vector.

Comment: thank you for your awesome answer. would you please take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195270/gradient-of-coefficient-of-variation-of-weighted-geometric-mean) too.

Comment: that question is just another version of this one. WM is replaced with exp(WM). @greg